# Mix vector of column names with mathematical statements in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Using `data.table`, I would like to turn a statement such as

```
dat <- data.table(x1=1:10, x2=1:10, x3=21:30)
dat[, list(newcol=x1+2, x2, x3)]
```

Into something like the following, which doesn't work:

```
columns <- c("x2","x3")
dat[, list(newcol=x1+2, columns)]
```

If all I wanted to select was the list of columns in the `columns` variable, than I would do

```
dat[, columns, with=F]
```

But in this example I also want to create the column `newcol`. Is there a workaround?

Comment: What is the problem here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
dat[, list(newcol=x1+2), by=columns]
#      x2 x3 newcol
#  1:  1 21      3
#  2:  2 22      4
#  3:  3 23      5
#  4:  4 24      6
#  5:  5 25      7
#  6:  6 26      8
#  7:  7 27      9
#  8:  8 28     10
#  9:  9 29     11
# 10: 10 30     12
```

Comment: Thanks, the first solution works. The second solution doesn't quite work because newcol gets added to the original data.table instead of just being part of the return value.

Answer (score 3):

I think in an ideal world I'd like this to work:

```
dat[, c(list(newcol=x1+2), mget(columns))]
```

But it doesn't, because `mget` arguments are not being processed to decide if more columns should be added to the internal `data.table` environment (perhaps OP can add a feature request about this).

One workaround for the above is adding *all* columns to the environment:

```
dat[, {.SD; c(list(newcol=x1+2), mget(columns))}]
#    newcol x2 x3
# 1:      3  1 21
# 2:      4  2 22
# 3:      5  3 23
# 4:      6  4 24
# 5:      7  5 25
# 6:      8  6 26
# 7:      9  7 27
# 8:     10  8 28
# 9:     11  9 29
#10:     12 10 30
```